# Order by doc_count in composite aggregation (or suitable alternatives)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a search like the following

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": { "...": "..." },
    "_source": false,
    "aggregations": {
        "agg1": { "...": "..." },
        "agg2": { "...": "..." }
    }
}
```

where `agg*` is composite aggregation of the kind

```
"agg1" : {
    "composite": {
        "size": 300,
        "sources": [
            {
                "field1": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "field1.keyword",
                        "missing_bucket": true,
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "field2": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "field2.keyword",
                        "missing_bucket": true,
                        "order": "asc"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "field3": {
            "filter": { "term": { "field3.keyword": "xyz" } }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to order by doc_count of the buckets as I don't need all the buckets, but just the top n, like what happens in some Kibana visualizations. From the documentation of [composite aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_order) it doesn't seem possible to order the results similarly at what happens with [terms aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). Is there a workaround or alternative queries to do this?

Comment: [Bucket sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html) aggregation might do this. Its sorts, and truncates based on values of other sub-aggregations and count too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (ugly) workaround is to define a [bucket sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html) pipeline aggregation and sort for id count:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": { "...": "..." },
    "_source": false,
    "aggregations": {
        "agg1": {
            "composite": {
                "size": 100,
                "sources": [
                     {
                        "field1": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "field1.keyword",
                                "missing_bucket": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "field2": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "field2.keyword",
                                "missing_bucket": true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggs": {
                "agg1_sort": {
                    "bucket_sort": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "agg1_doc_number": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "agg1_doc_number": {
                    "value_count": {
                        "field": "_id"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```